# wget many long URLs from a .txt file

Tags: wget

I have a couple hundred 10-second mp4s to download. The URLs to these files are listed in a file called urls.txt and they look like

```
http://v16.muscdn.com/thirty_two_alphanumeric_characters/5cf790de/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/thirty_two_alphanumeric_characters/?rc=ang7cmg8OmZtaTMzZzczM0ApQHRAbzVHOjYzMzM0NTQ2ODMzMzQ1b0BoNXYpQGczdyl2KUBmamxmc3JneXcxcHpAKTY0ZHEzY2otcTZyb18tLWIxNnNzLW8jbyM2QS8wLS00LTQtLzYzMjYtOiNvIzphLW8jOmA6YC1vI2toXitiZmBjYmJeYDAvOg%3D%3D
```

so the total length of the url is 329 characters.

When I try wget -i urls.txt I get `Error 414 URI Too Long`

But when I try to wget a random URL from the file by copy/pasting it into my terminal it works fine and downloads the one file.

So then I tried the following bash script to wget each URL in the file, but that gave me the same error.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo "Text read from file: $line"
wget $line --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22"
done < "urls.txt"
```

I also tried to change the line-ending characters by doing dos2unix on the file but it made no difference.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

If all your URLs are already in a single file, why don't you simply invoke wget as:

```
$ wget  --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22" -i urls.txt
```